# How can i determine all special character inputed?

Tags: javascript

How can i set the range of all special character? missing code here /....../
.............................................................................

script.js

```
<script>
 //validate special character
if ( pswd.match(/......./) ) {
    $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
} else {
    $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
}

//validate capital letter
if ( pswd.match(/[A-Z]/) ) {
    $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
} else {
    $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
}

//validate number
if ( pswd.match(/\d/) ) {
    $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
} else {
    $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(pswd)`

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you mean by special character?

Comment: i mean all none letter and numbers

Comment: not letter or number*

Answer (score -1):

use ASCII values instead.
Convert password string into the character array and compare it against ASCII values of alphabets.ASCII values of alphabets mentioned below.
**A-Z=95-120** and 
**a-z=65-90**